# QT send file by http request POST

Tags: c++, node.js, qt, http, file-upload

I work with Qt and I try to send by http request a file like an image or a video to my NodeJS server.
I have a problem with the data send, when I read the file and I send to the server the data I don't receive the good character. I guess the problem come from the unicode, utf16 or something like that because it is working with a file.txt and not with an image.jpg

This is my function where I read and send the file. This one is called until the read function ended.

```
   void FileManager::sendFileDataToServer(QString pathFile, QString location) {
    CredentailsTable cdt;

    if (_qfile->isOpen())
    {
        QString data;

        if (!_in->atEnd()) {

            data = _in->read(_socketManager->getBufferSize()); // read file

            cdt.addCredential("name", getNameFile(_pathSendFile)); // set data
            cdt.addCredential("msg", data);

            _fileRequest->request(FileRequest::POST, FileRequest::Write, cdt);
        }
        else {
            _qfileTest->close();
            qDebug("End file");
        }
    }
    else
        qDebug("Error open file");
}
```

This function is called every time when the server respond

```
void FileManager::responseSendFileDataToServer(QNetworkReply *reply) {
    if (reply->error() != 0)
    {
        qDebug("Il y a eu une erreur sur le server %d", reply->error());
        return ;
    }
    else
        this->sendFileDataToServer(_pathSendFile, _locationFileServer);
}
```

This is where my request is send

```
void ServiceRequest::request(Type type, int request, QByteArray cdt) {
    QString strRequest = "REQUEST : http://" + _host + _prefixRoute + getRoute(request);

    qDebug(strRequest.toStdString().c_str());
    switch (type) {
    case POST: {
        QNetworkRequest networkRequest = QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://" + _host + _prefixRoute + getRoute(request)));
        networkRequest.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        QNetworkReply *replyPost = this->post(networkRequest, cdt);
        connect(replyPost, static_cast<void(QNetworkReply::*)(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)>(&QNetworkReply::error), this, &ServiceRequest::slotError);
        connect(replyPost, &QNetworkReply::sslErrors, this, &ServiceRequest::slotSslErrors);
        break;
    }
```

My nodeJS function :

```
var write = function(req, res) {
  fs.appendFile("users/" + req.body.name, req.body.msg, "UCS2",
  function(err) {
      return res.status(200).json(err);
  })
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using QDataStream or QByteArray instead of QString to read your data?